# Batch replacing values in multiple SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a reference code that can appear in many tables and need to change a number of references. I have produced a list of all tables and fields that need to be updated: e.g.

```
  Table1.Reference,  
  Table2.Ref_Code, 
  Table3.Reference_Code
```

and need to change the references in all of the above instances, for example:

```
 000123 to 00123 / 000456 to 00456
```

My original method was to create a huge list of:

```
UPDATE Table SET Reference = '00123' WHERE Reference = '000123'
```

for every field I need to update and then repeat for every reference I need to change. However, as I need to change 24 references, the resultant ~4000 line query wasn't efficient.

I also have to deal with the fact that some tables MAY be empty (returning a resultant 'String or binary data would be truncated') so I possibly need to consider adding 'if exists...' in there.

Comment: You're working both in MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry - happy clicking :)! SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: have you remove all reference leading zero?

Comment: Due to the sensitive nature of my data, I provided dummy references. The references I wish to change begin with 1-9 (i.e. no leading zero). One example of an actual change is 15000190 to 1500190.

Comment: Is it always going to be three zeros in the middle of a number being converted to two zeros in the middle of a number?

Comment: An empty table, in and of itself, should never cause the error `String or binary data would be truncated` so if you're getting that, there's some other cause or something else you've not told us about.

Comment: @StuartAinsworth: Unfortunately not, it is a string so may be alpha-numeric.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The line UPDATE Table29 SET Reference = '1500190' WHERE Reference = '15000190' returned that error. When I checked Table29, it was empty (and assumed that was the issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better solution to this is to have a mapping table. The table should have the structure like :

Table Name : ReferenceMap

OldReference  |     NewReference

000123      |       00123

000465      |       00465

```
Update Table
Set Reference = map.NewReference
From ReferenceMap map
Where reference = map.OldReference
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Great! Used a temporary table, inserted values with INSERT INTO and then only required UPDATE, SET, FROM, WHERE once for each table/column. Thank you.